# Progress bar terminated and goes into new screen

Tags: android, android-intent

```
package com.example.progress;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ProgressActivity extends Activity  {
ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProgressActivity.this,
                "Please wait...", "few seconds.....", true);

new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                try{
                        // Do some Fake-Work
                        sleep(5000);
                } catch (Exception e) { }
                myProgressDialog.dismiss();



        }
}.start();
}
};
```

This is my code... What I want now is when progress bar finishes, i want to go into next screen....

Even tho I know how to go into other screen with using buttons.. I am not able to implement it....

I tried this...

Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, screen2.class);
                                     startActivity(i);

Add this line of code and replace with the progress.dismiss();

But it didn't work out... Please just show me a source code or any help... I just want to get to other screen...

I am new to this... and want to learn it... Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Please further explain "But it didn't work out". Error logs? Crashes? ANR (Application Not Responding) message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Handler it is very easy...

```
private Handler handler=new Handler(){

    @Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
{
Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, screen2.class); 
startActivity(i);
myProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

and In Oncreate method you need to send message to handler whenever you want;

```
handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 5000);//after 5000 millisec msg will be send
```